# TypeScript: Cannot assign empty array to array of my own type

Tags: typescript, types

I have an interface called `Converter`

```
export interface Converter<T> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => Promise<T>;
  encode?: (value: T) => Promise<Buffer>;
}
```

And I am using an array of that in another file:

```
import{ Converter } from "./characteristic";

export type Converters = Converter<any>[];

export default class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters: C;

  constructor(converters: C = []) {
           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error
    this.converters = converters;
  }
}
```

I am getting an error when I want to assign an empty array as an initial value to that property:

> ```
> Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'C'.
>   'never[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Converter<any>[]'.ts(2322)
> ```

I have tried changing my type to

```
export type Converters = Converter<any>[] | [];
```

without any luck

I *can* do this:

```
export default class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters: C | [] = [];
}
```

but I am not sure why I have to or if that even is an appropriate solution and not just a anti-pattern workaround. I don't even understand what the problem is here.

Comment: Right off the top of my head I cannot see why it doesn't work. But it might be helpful to know which version of TypeScript you are using?

Comment: Hey  @fredrik I am using TypeScript `3.5.3`

Comment: It doesn't work because you can specify a more specific type such as `[Converter<string>]` (a one-tuple type) for `C`, and you can't assign the value `[]` to a one-tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
export interface Converter<T = any> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => Promise<T>;
  encode?: (value: T) => Promise<Buffer>;
}

export default class Service<C extends Converter> {
  private converters: C[];

  constructor(converters: C[] = []) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }
}
```

I think `export type Converters = Converter<any>[];` must obscure that it is an array so it tries to compare `never[]` to `Converters` instead of `[]` (with possibility to `.push(Converter)`) to `Converter[]`.

Edit: actually if the the Service is intended to only have Converters of a certain type not mixed (I don't know) it might be better to do:

```
export interface Converter<T> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => Promise<T>;
  encode?: (value: T) => Promise<Buffer>;
}

export default class Service<T> {
  private converters: Converter<T>[];

  constructor(converters: Converter<T>[] = []) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey William. Thank you, but this won't work for me. The Converters can have multiple types.

Comment: "This won't work for me" ... Wait, *why* doesn't the first solution given here with types like `class Service<C extends Converter> { converters: C[];  constructor(converters: C[] = []) { ... }}` work for you?  `C` can be a union.  If it really doesn't work I think we need a [mcve] that shows why.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was assuming that the first the solution will work on an array of the same converter type, which I see now it is not. I kept working on my "thing" and have created another, more elaborate question where I am tacking the problem. I will close this question in favor of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812051/typescript-union-of-a-specific-property-of-items-in-array Sorry for the effort you have already put into this, but the other one is probably more precisely what I am trying to do