# TypeScript: Union of a specific property of items in array

Tags: typescript

> **TLDR; VERSION**

*Edit, I have added a Playground, Link at the bottom*

I have an array ob objects in TypeScript.

```
interface Converter<T = Buffer> {
  name: string;
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => T;
}

const infoConverter: Converter<string> = {
  name: "info",
  uuid: "180a",
  decode: v => v.toString()
};

const pressureConverter: Converter<number> = {
  name: "pressure",
  uuid: "1810",
  decode: v => v.readInt32BE(0)
};

type MyConverters = [Converter<string>, Converter<number>]

const converters: MyConverters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter];
```

Now I am asking if it possible to write a type that is a union of all the `name`s in that array:

```
type Name<Converters[]> = "???";
// type Name<MyConverters> =  "info" | "pressure"
```

and a type that is a generic corresponding to a name

```
type Value<Converters[], name extends string>
type Value<MyConverters, "pressure"> = number;
```

---

> **EXPLANATION WHAT I AM DOING AND WHY**

I am writing a [Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Library for Node called Sblendid](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgVwGZKgJxgXhgOwQWwCN0BuGAenJgCsEBnEGJAewxAAtY6BDAa1mZIYHAJZ0YEADbcwAczTMEOACahIsAMIBVLQEkAIllwFiGAD4wGaETlklgwGyHRJuAY03McAN3TO0ADwAKkaIKOgAfDAA3sAwuNz4UABcliDWtvbxCAgiyqnaevpZMMpQbsxlqQAU3tySCCnwyKhoAJRYUUH2AL4O4NAwGl6+aP7i2MM+fugB3DhgEQDaALr2A7AAcolQAPJohQYBGlGTMFAAHs4q4lOj4zAA-DDbScdRBToG9mqDr1DHc5XKA3IYjGZoOinGAAIhsLBhMAsMIgaCgdDoCDRMPW6hgADV6o1jgAaF5A67KcT-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-IeOaibKNUckIqewDNWNE1QJlRidd1vLjW1Nn2MN8nMGt2DLW1mVTVASazRp2kwqeQA) with which you can talk to BLE peripherals. BLE peripherals have `Services` from which you can read from and write values to (amongst other things). These sort of "Endpoints" of the Service are called `Characteristics` and they have IDs (UUIDs).

When you read a Characteristic you need to say which UUID you want to address and the return value will be binary data (usually a `Buffer` in Node).

So to make life easier for users of the library I want to create an API that lets them provide what I call `Converters` that look like this:

```
interface Converter<T = Buffer> {
  name: string;
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => T;
}

type Converters = Converter<any>[];
```

So now when somebody wants to talk to a `Service` on a peripheral they should be able to pass their converters to the `Service` and can now address their `Characteristics` by a name and will get their decoded values instead of binary data when the read a `Characteristic`, like so:

```
const infoConverter: Converter<string> = {
  name: "info",
  uuid: "180a",
  decode: v => v.toString()
};

const pressureConverter: Converter<number> = {
  name: "pressure",
  uuid: "1810",
  decode: v => v.readInt32BE(0)
};

const converters: Converters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter];

const service = new Service(converters);
const info = await service.read("info");
//    ^^^^                       ^^^^ 
//    this will be a string     their name instead of a UUID (like "a002")
```

I "already" have a working implementation, but as I am writing everything in `TypeScript`, I need to get the typings right.

What I want to achieve is that if a user provides the `converters` as in the example, this:

```
const service = new Service(converters);
const info = await service.read("infoasdasd");
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

should trigger an error saying that this is not a name in your `converters` array. Also TypeScript should understand that this

```
const service = new Service(converters);
const info = await service.read("infoasdasd");
//    ^^^^
```

is a string, because of what you wrote in your `converters`.

Because this all seems easy enough, I want users to be able to work without `converters`. So if they create a `Service` without `converters`

```
const service = new Service();
const info = service.read("180a");
//    ^^^^                 ^^^^
//    Buffer               any CUUID (string | number)
```

They should be able to pass any Characteristic UUID and will get a Buffer as return value. The implementation works. I am struggling with teaching `TypeScript` how to type this.

So far I got this:

```
type CUUID = number | string;

interface Converter<T = Buffer> {
  name: string;
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => T;
}

type Converters = Converter<any>[];
type NameOrCUUID<C> = C extends Converters ? Name<C> : CUUID;

type Name<C extends Converters> = "info" | "pressure";
type Value<C, N extends NameOrCUUID<C>> = "" | Buffer;

class Service<C> {
  private converters?: Converters;

  constructor(converters?: C) {
    this.converters = converters as any; // Ask on StackOverflow
  }

  public read<N extends NameOrCUUID<C>>(name: N): Value<C, N> {
    if (this.converters) {
      return this.getConvertedValue(name);
    } else {
      return this.getBufferForUUID(name);
    }
  }

  private getBufferForUUID(uuid: CUUID): Buffer {
    return Buffer.from("Foobar", "utf8"); // Dummy Code
  }

  private getConvertedValue<N extends NameOrCUUID<C>>(name: N): Value<C, N> {
    return "Foobar"; // Dummy Code
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not the actual implementation for the BLE. With this code I am trying to get the typings right. So what I am trying is to tell `read` that it can accept a `NameOrCUUID`, which, depending on if the `Service` class has a generic that is `Converters` will either a `name` of the `Converters` or if there was no generic passed to the `Service` class will accept any Characteristic UUID.

This works. When I call this code:

```
const service = new Service(converters);
const info = service.read("info");

const service2 = new Service();
const info2 = service2.read("180a");
```

and pass the `converters` from way up there as a parameter it will tell me that I can only pass `info` or `pressure`. I I do not pass any converters at all (`service2`) I can pass any number or string.

But this is only fake because Implementations for

```
type Name<C extends Converters> = "???";
type Value<C, N extends NameOrCUUID<C>> = "???";
```

For this, and this and this is the part I cannot figure out.

I would need to tell `TypeScript` to allow the `name` properties of any item in `Converters` likewise with the values, and the values must match the name.

Ok sorry for the wall of text. I hope I could express what I am asking (that last paragraph is the actual question). I wonder if that is even possible in TypeScript.

Here is a Playground:

[This elaborate example on typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgVwGZKgJxgXhgOwQWwCN0BuGAenJgCsEBnEGJAewxAAtY6BDAa1mZIYHAJZ0YEADbcwAczTMEOACahIsAMIBVLQEkAIllwFiGAD4wGaETlklgwGyHRJuAY03McAN3TO0ADwAKkaIKOgAfDAA3sAwuNz4UABcliDWtvbxCAgiyqnaevpZMMpQbsxlqQAU3tySCCnwyKhoAJRYUUH2AL4O4NAwGl6+aP7i2MM+fugB3DhgEQDaALr2A7AAcolQAPJohQYBGlGTMFAAHs4q4lOj4zAA-DDbScdRBToG9mqDr1DHc5XKA3IYjGZoOinGAAIhsLBhMAsMIgaCgdDoCDRMPW6hgADV6o1jgAaF5A67KcT-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-IeOaibKNUckIqewDNWNE1QJlRidd1vLjW1Nn2MN8nMGt2DLW1mVTVASazRp2kwqeQA)

Comment: "tuple" might be a good keyword to add here (ie what `MyConverters` is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that your type annotations of `infoConverter` as `Converter<string>` and `pressureConverter` as `Converter<number>` are too wide.  The compiler will dutifully forget that `infoConverter.name` is `"info"`, and instead will use the type annotation that says it is a `string`.

I think you will get closer to what you want by just using type inference and a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) to get the narrowest possible types for your converter instances:

```
const infoConverter = {
  name: "info",
  uuid: "180a",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v.toString()
} as const;

const pressureConverter = {
  name: "pressure",
  uuid: "1810",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v / 1024
} as const;

const converters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter] as const;
```

At this point there's no guarantee that the elements of `converters` conform to your `Converter` interface, but you can make sure that any functions that accept `converters` or types that accept `typeof converters` are constrained to `Converter<any>[]` and you'll get an error there if `converters` has a mistake.

So let's look at those two type functions you want... given an array of `Converter` types, get the list of `name`s, and a mapping of `name` to `value` type.  How about:

```
type Names<C extends ReadonlyArray<Converter<any>>> = C[number]["name"];

type Value<
  C extends ReadonlyArray<Converter<any>>,
  N extends Names<C>
> = Extract<C[number], { name: N }> extends Converter<infer V> ? V : never;
```

Note that I constrain `C` to `ReadonlyArray<Converter<any>>` and not `Array<Converter<any>>`... this is a looser constraint (the `Array` interface is an extension of the `ReadonlyArray` interface; every `Array` is a `ReadonlyArray` but not vice versa; the naming is perhaps a bit misleading; maybe it should be `ReadableAndWritableArray` for `Array` and `ReadableArray` for `ReadonlyArray`... but I digress).  That's so that `C` will accept `typeof converters`, which is a [`readonly tuple`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#readonly-tuples).

Anyway, the `Names` type alias [looks up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `"name"` property type from the `number`-indexed elements of the `C` array.  And the `Value` type alias [`Extract`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) the elements of `C` that have a `name` property matching `N`, and then [infers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) the value type from it.

Does it work?

```
type TheNames = Names<typeof converters>; // "info" | "pressure"
type InfoValue = Value<typeof converters, "info">; // string
type PressureValue = Value<typeof converters, "pressure">; // number
```

Looks good to me.  Note that the above lines have no compiler errors, so the `converters` object must be correctly meeting the constraint of being a (possibly readonly) array of `Converter` elements.

Hopefully you can use this to get your expanded example code working.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgMwRATlAvFAdnAtgI1QG4oB6UqAKzgGdgoEB7NYAC2hoEMBraRhKGwCWNKGAA2nEAHMUjOFgAmAKFCQoAYQCqWgJIARDNjyE0AHyh0UQrNKLLlN4KgScAxtA2MsAN1TOUAB4AFSN4JFQAPigAb2UobE5cCAAuS2BrW3sEuDghRTTtPX1sqEUIN0ZytIAKH05xOFTYRGQUAEoMaOD7AF8HSqw6KBsmL19-VCM4hKwk5oAiUcYFgBp4qFz8tIWARgAOAAZONY3yyuqoOrTwts70aJ8AOmBGAGUMm2ka9uVeqE4okGdHsymB9DAKAgNBocCh4z8KAC0w2c2SO0h0NhUNOOTyBSge32u0OuLKFSqzWuLQiHS6UB8ZCgJIATAAWP4AoHeEEDHn0QaIgKiTAAbWWCMmKFWYihMLhEElSNQAF0uVBwaC1NAAHLzGiBDRQCAAD2cSlEACUIJxFN5xCAAIIoFBSQ3eIWoQKcLAgSL+owaUU4Aiq0ULNEQBYqrXgaAANQaTUCGyNpvNiitNrtWAdztdIHdE2VQR9fsi6wSOuNZogFqgeuSBo0kWU0UwAFEza63MBDcGTKqZTFEuiG1BetF03XM5oPVLAqMpvHogB+KDxqBpLAQRGx9TBdiN6FGY8G7X8DXzks0SIkciE5YLKAWBaY+U41RxqC6LBMRONNAmAAcmF4CIKUo0DKSx-isd5kBQVhfF+6gAApytiEAgUBG5JhAgRgVexbCtB76YQs8EPiGpjKEAA)

Comment: Ich have a question. I understand why the `const` assignment is necessary, but when I comment it out, it still works. Which I do not get, because what you are saying totally makes sense!

Comment: Can't post a link because the url is too long but if you do `const converters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter];// as const;` in line 22 it still works!

Comment: The `const` assertions in the `infoConverter` and `pressureConverter` definition are helpful, since without them you'd need some other way to make sure that the `"info"` and `"pressure"` names don't widen.   But once `infoConverter` and `pressureConverter` are already narrow, it's true that you don't need a `const` assertion in the `converters` definition, since all that does is retain the order of the two entries, and your code doesn't really care about that.   I wouldn't say `as const` is ever *necessary*; it's just one of the most convenient ways to keep inferences narrow.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, you're a legend!