# TypeScript assertion on every item of array

Tags: typescript

[I defined an array of an `interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57812051/1183252)

```
interface Converter<T = Buffer> {
  name: string;
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: Buffer) => T;
}

type Converters = ReadonlyArray<Converter<any>>;
```

but for my usecase I need to cast every item in that array using a `const` assertion:

```
const infoConverter = {
  name: "info",
  uuid: "180a",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v.toString()
} as const;

const pressureConverter = {
  name: "pressure",
  uuid: "1810",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v.readInt32BE(0)
} as const;

const converters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter];
```

I would not mind doing that, but I am writing a library and users of that library are providing that array. So in order for the library to work properly I will have to ask the users to use a `const` assertion whenever they work with it, which is not quite optimal.

For me, it would be great if the could just provide the library with their data and I could automatically do a `const` assertion.

So  I have this class

```
class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters?: Converters;

  constructor(converters?: C) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }
}
```

and I wonder if there is a way I could do something like this:

```
class Service<C extends Converters> {
  private converters?: EveryItemIsAConst<Converters>;

  constructor(converters?: C) {
    this.converters = converters as EveryItemIsAConst<C>;
  }
}
```

and the users could just do

```
const infoConverter = {
  name: "info",
  uuid: "180a",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v.toString()
};

const pressureConverter = {
  name: "pressure",
  uuid: "1810",
  decode: (v: Buffer) => v.readInt32BE(0)
};

const converters = [infoConverter, pressureConverter];

const service = new Service(converters)
```

and the `EveryItemIsAConst` would make sure `as const` is applied to every item in the `converters` array.

Comment: The problem with the code at the end is that by the time you get to `new Service(converters)` the compiler has already widened the type of `converters[0].name` and `converters[1].name` to `string`, and there's no way to get it back.  There are different ways to keep string literals narrow but all of them will require users of `Service` to do *something*.  e.g., `const infoConverter = {...} as const`, or `const infoConverter = asConverter({})` (for an appropriate `asConverter()` function).

Comment: Alright, thank you so much!